# Objective-c memory leak in my function

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

can anyone help me in finding the memory leak in the following function

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding :(NSString *)string {
    return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,  (CFStringRef)string,  NULL,  (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",  CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

Instrument is reporting memory leak in every call of the above function.

Comment: You do release the result after you've done with it, don't you?

Comment: @Alexander After return? will that statement execute after return ?

Comment: Not after return, after you're done using the result of the function ( `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` creates a copy of the string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` adds +1 retain count as you own that object. So you are responsible to release that object. So You need to have `CFStringRef` and after using you object use `CFRelease` to release that.

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding :(NSString *)string {
    CFStringRef stringRef = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,  (CFStringRef)string,  NULL,  (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",  CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
    NSString *returnString = (NSString*)stringRef;
    CFRelease(stringRef);
    return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on whether you are using ARC or not.

With ARC you can transfer ownership:

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding :(NSString *)string {
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,  (CFStringRef)string,  NULL,  (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",  CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

With MRC you can do:

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding :(NSString *)string {
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,  (CFStringRef)string,  NULL,  (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",  CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));

    return [result autorelease];
}
```